# how to reserve a CPU register in armclang for AARCH64

Tags: gcc, arm, clang, llvm, compiler-flags

I am looking to do an experiment where in I can reserve ARM CPU register, say X25 to be not used by the compiler. Looking at the armclang reference document that says,

> **Syntax**
> -ffixed-rN
>
> **Parameters**
> N specifies the register number, which can be any number
> from 5 to 11. This enables you to reserve core registers R5 to R11.
>
> **Restrictions** This feature is only available for AArch32 state.

Does that mean I cannot use this option in 64-bit architecture ? In that case how can i reserve a particular CPU register with armclang compiler ?